# Operation CRUD with edmx and objectdatasource error Idisposable

Tags: c#, objectdatasource, edmx

I have 3 tiers apps.

In the Persistance layer the is just the drag 'n' drop Entities.edmx file.

In the Presentation layer :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource_Tva" runat="server" 
        DeleteMethod="del_Tva" InsertMethod="Inst_Tva" 
        SelectMethod="Get_All_Tva" 
        TypeName="FaExped_BackEnd_WebApp_Business.Le_T.LeTVA_Entite_BL" 
        UpdateMethod="Updt_Tva">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Libelle" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Libelle" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And a gridview that connects to this objectdatasource.

In my busines logic layer, when I use it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T_TVA> Get_All_Tva()
{
    FaExpedEntities oEntite_T = new FaExpedEntities();
    var query = from o in oEntite_T.T_TVA select o;
    IEnumerable<T_TVA> LesTva = query;
    return LesTva;       
}
```

It works, but when I use like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T_TVA> Get_All_Tva()
{
    using (FaExpedEntities oEntite_T = new FaExpedEntities())
    {
        var query = from o in oEntite_T.T_TVA select o;
        IEnumerable<T_TVA> LesTva = query;
        return LesTva;
    }         
}
```

It does not work.  It said that the instance of `ObjectContext` has been deleted and cannot be used for operations that require a connection.

Why?

What is the difference such that using "`using`" syntax fails and not using "`using`" works?

Which is the better approach, with or without the "`using`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your error with the code that has the `using` statement is due to **deferred execution**. Essentially it means that the database connection has been closed *before* the LINQ query is executed to retrieve the results.

One common work around is to 'force' the LINQ query to be immediately executed using a non deferred operator like `ToList()`.

There are plenty of [good](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx) on MSDN regarding deferred execution which applies to all types of LINQ, not just using LINQ with Entity Framework.